# Javascript as a link

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, href

I am making a website. In this the contents of a particular div has changes using Javascript and json when the user selects a link.

The problem I am facing is that that I am not able to use the back button since all my links for changing the div contents are like:

```
<a href=" **some javascript function**">
```

How should I change this as to use the default back/forward buttons effectively.

I know that it can be used to navigate to divs by using #, but the problem is that all my links are in the same div.

Is there any way the back button can execute a previously executed javascript?

Comment: Maybe you could use something like http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js/). Also `<a href="javascript:…">` is a really bad practice. Use `<a>` to reference other documents / files, not (directly) invoke javascript functions.